# How can I choose a different icon for each Saved Places list?

Tags: google-maps

Have there been any changes since [this question was originally asked](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/maps/kR4bNrOWMbE/CT-eybSlAgAJ)?

> I can't find the option to change the colors of my Save Places list. All my lists are in light blue.

[image]

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 9):

It is not currently possible to do that in your Saved Places.
People keep posting feedback to request that.
You could do so as well.

But **there is an option**. There are other more customizable "User Maps", inherited from the old Google Maps (one of the few things across the Google landscape that were more useful in an older version and it was not killed).

Go to *Three bar menu* -> *Your Places* -> *Maps* (instead of *Saved*) -> *CREATE MAP* (at the bottom).

You could also import maps there, and AFAIR I exported a map from SAVED and imported it in MAPS, to be able to customize it.

This is a sample map I created about 5 years ago.

[image]

I am not sure the level of customization currently allowed is the same as before.
But you can still change colors, use groups of markers within a map and configure each group separately, use sequential placemark numbers within a group, etc.
Tinker a little.

See also

https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/2679986?hl=en

https://support.google.com/mymaps/answer/3024925?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en

Comment: The one flaw with this method is that there is no way to keep My Maps displayed. You can set Lists to be shown or not, but My Maps clear as soon as you exit that mode. Google seem to have abandoned the feature.

Answer (score 3):

@sancho.s, while this would work, these "my maps" dont work offline or in downloaded maps. So just note; using this requires connection, or to export them out of Google maps and use another offline map application to import into that would work. The value of "Starred" and the rest is they are part of the downloaded maps in Google.

Answer (score 2):

You just can't. There is no such feature on Google Maps which would allow you to do so. Your only option is to send feedback and requesting such a feature:

[image: 0]

Answer (score 2):

This is now possible! Though it only seems to be supported in the iOS and Android apps, rather than on the web. I can assign custom icons to my lists on mobile, and view them on mobile, but the generic "list" icon still appears on the web.

To set an icon:

- Open the mobile app
- Go to the Saved tab
- Under "Your lists", tap More to see your custom lists
- Choose a list, tap the 3-dot button on the right, then tap "Edit list"
- At the top of the page, tap "Edit icon"
- Now you can choose a custom emoji, which will be used to designate all the items in this list when you view your map
- If you don't see the places on your map, the list may be hidden; tap the 3-dot button again and choose "Show on your map"